# Is it possible to get MacOS desktop notifications via Google Chrome for Google Calendar if you do not have a Google Calendar window open?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, google-calendar

I think I've tried everything and now I'm thinking this is not possible? Is anyone able to confirm or deny that this?

It's really frustrating to not get a notification if I happen to not have a Google Calendar browser tab open.

Here are my settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how it works these days, because I haven't used it in years, but I used to have my Mac Calendar subscribed to my Google calendar with [CalDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV). That let the Mac's alert system work just fine.